# Giving eval the correct context

Tags: javascript, angular, eval

In Angular my `eval()` is not working in the correct context.

I just want to test it with something simple like `eval('console.log(this.sharedservice.var1)');` but says `Cannot read property 'sharedservice' of undefined`, so it doesn't know what `this` is.

When I try to do `(0, eval)(script);` which solves the `this` problem, then it says `Cannot read property 'var1' of undefined`. So know it doesn't know what `sharedservice` is. But in my component's constructor I do have `private sharedservice: SharedService,`. How can help eval see my component's constructor values?

Please don't suggest not to use eval, so tired of this argument.

Comment: Consider this the ["Obligatory don't use eval message"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197769/when-is-javascripts-eval-not-evil)

Answer (score 0):

You should not use [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Do_not_ever_use_eval!). Is what you will hear from a lot of people. If you still want to use eval, you can try this:

```
export class BadIdea {
  constructor(private sharedservice: SharedService) {
    ((evalThis) => eval(evalThis)).call(this, 'console.log(this.lm.test)');
  }
}
```